# Accessing 3 table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

i want to copy data from one table to another table. how?

```
$P_studentnumber=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentnumber']);
$P_subjectcode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subjectcode']);
$P_semester=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['semester']);

$sql "INSERT units INTO grades (units) FROM subjects WHERE subjectcode='$P_subjectcode'"; //<--THIS IS THE PART THAT I WOULD WANT TO ADD

$sql="INSERT INTO grades (studentnumber,course, subjectcode, semester, instructorname, units) SELECT '$P_studentnumber', course, '$P_subjectcode', '$P_semester','$instructorname', 'units' FROM students WHERE studentnumber='$P_studentnumber'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
INSERT table1(col1,col2) SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

INSERT into site_constants_description
SELECT site_constants_description_new.*
FROM site_constants_description_new, site_language
WHERE site_language.site_language_id = site_constants_description_new.site_language_id;

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL Syntax of `SELECT...INSERT` statement is:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM tableB
WHERE colA = 'valueHere' -- this statement here is the condition
```

You must remember that the column name (or *field*) **must match** with each other. If the column you want to `INSERT` does not match, you can still `INSERT` but you will provide an `ALIAS` for that.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT fieldA as colA, fieldB as colB, fieldC as colC
FROM tableB
WHERE fieldA = 'valueHere' -- this statement here is the condition
```

same for `JOINED` tables:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT tableB.fieldA as colA, tableB.fieldB as colB, tableC.fieldC as colC
FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableC ON tableB.fieldA = tableC.fieldA
WHERE tableC.fieldA = 'valueHere' -- this statement here is the condition
```